# Grab the dollar Bayesian game

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory

$\epsilon_i$ is distributed uniformly on $[-\phi, \phi] $ where $\phi>1$. My working so far is as follows: $$\mathbb{E}U_1[I]=1+\epsilon_1\\\mathbb{E}U[N]=0\\$$ Therefore, the optimal strategy for player 1 is for all $\epsilon_1>-1$ to play $I$ and for all $\epsilon_2<-1$ to play $U$. This strategy specification is the same for player 2. In terms of pinning-down a BNE, I am lost beyond this point. Thank you.   [image]

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathbb{E}U_1[I]=1+\epsilon_1$? And what does the LHS even mean - there is no indication of what strategy player 2 plays...?

Comment: @VARulle Because if player 1 plays $I$ then player 2 will respond by playing N, and so player 1 gets $1+\epsilon_1$.

Comment: Are you saying that player 1 moves first?

Comment: @VARulle No; it is a simultaneous move game.

Comment: Then how can player 2 "respond by playing N", if he doesn't observe player 1's choice of I?

Comment: @VARulle The payoff structure is common knowledge, so he knows that player 2 will play N if he plays $I$.

Comment: But they choose simultaneously. So how should player 1 know that he played $I$?

Comment: Or, on a more technical level: In a game, $U_i$ is always a function of the chosen strategy *profile*, not of player $i$'s chosen strategy alone!

Comment: @VARulle I understand that but am entirely lost in my approach to this problem. How would you suggest I approach it? Thank you.

Comment: First, in the question you should clarify who knows which $\epsilon_i$ at what point in time.